# Converting Char buffer into an array of shorts

Tags: c, casting, char, buffer, short

I have a char * buffer that is filled by an API function. I need to take the data that is contained with that pointer, cast it to unsigned shorts and translate it into network (htons()) format to send it over UDP.  Here is my code (not all though for a few reasons)

The code below will work but that data on the other side is bad (not shorts or network translated)

```
    char * pcZap;
    while(1)
    {
        unsigned short *ps;
        unsigned short short_buffer[4096];

        write_reg(to start xfer);
        return_val = get_packet(fd, &pcZap, &uLen, &uLob);
        check_size_of_uLen_and_uLob(); //make sure we got a packet

        // here I need to chage pcZap to (unsigned short *) and translate to network            

        sendto(sockFd,pcZap,size,0,(struct sockaddr *)Server_addr,
               sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        return_val = free_packet(fd, pcZap);
        thread_check_for_exit();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to translate it to again ? How many "shorts" are there ?

Comment: the bad thing is I cannot be sure of how many "shorts" are in the char buffer I get back from get_packet(), all I know is the size of the buffer I requested and if it was filled properly or not. I do know that the header of the char * i get back is 4 32 bit words, every word after that is 2 16 bit samples (shorts) up to the size I requested. -edit (I should know the size, since I give it a size and the first 4 32 bit words are the header to 4096-16 4080 is the size of my samples buffer)

Comment: If you don't know how many there are, how can you copy them ?

Comment: 1020 is how many 16 bit sample i have contained in the buffer.

Comment: @blsmit5728 it sounds like perhaps the uLen or uLob or return_val will give you back the size of the fetched data - please try to verify that, or it's embedded in the 4*32 bit header somehow. We can't guess that, as we don't have any documentation for the get_packet() etc. But once you know this, it's just a matter of writing a very simple loop.

Comment: @nos uLen contains the length of the total packet including the header, uLob is the size of the out-of-band data (header) I check those to make sure its not bigger that (4096 + 16) 16 being the header size.

Comment: Right, so you get `uLen - 16 - uLob` number of bytes for the samples (divide by 2 to get the no. of short ints)

Comment: well, or drop the `-16` if uLob also includes the 4*32 bit header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 4080 bytes in your buffer that are composed of 16-bit samples, that would mean you have 2040 total 16-bit samples in the 4080 bytes of your buffer (16-bytes are reserved for the header).  Therefore you can do the following:

```
#define MAXBUFSIZE 4096
#define MAXSHORTSIZE 2040

unsigned char pcZap[MAXBUFSIZE];
unsigned ushort[MAXSHORTSIZE];

//get the value of the returned packed length in uLen, and the header in uLob

unsigned short* ptr = (unsigned short*)(pcZap + uLob);
for (int i=0; i < ((uLen - uLob) / 2); i++)
{
    ushort[i] = htons(*ptr++);
}
```

Now your `ushort` array will be composed of network-byte-order `unsigned short` values converted from the original values in the `pcZap` array.  Then, when you call `sendto()`, make sure to use the values from `ushort`, not the values from `pcZap`.

Comment: It looks like on the other side of my network I'm only getting the first 16 bit sample. shouldn't we be stepping through pcZap? pcZap++?

Comment: `ptr` is pointing to `pcZap` (a temporary pointer), and we increment that in the for-loop.  So as we increment the value of `ptr`, it points to the next unsigned short element in the array.

Comment: yes! got it! stupid me forgot to send the unsigned short buffer I was sending the ptr

Answer (score 0):

If your array of chars is null terminated then you can simply do:

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(CHAR_ARRAY); i++)
     short_buffer[i] = (unsigned short) CHAR_ARRAY[i];
```

If the array isn't null terminated then you'll need to figure out how long it is exactly and then replace `strlen(CHAR_ARRAY)` with that value.

Comment: I would need us to contain all of the unsigned short samples in the char buffer so I could cast it and send it. I'm going to take this and mold it to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is convert a chunk of bytes, representing short ints in host endian to network endian, you do this:

```
size_t i;
size_t len = uLen - 16 - uLob;
size_t offset = uLob + 16;

if(len % 2 != 0) {
  ..error not a multiple of 16 bit shorts...
}
//now, if you're on a little endian host (assuming the shorts in 
//pcZap is laid out as the host endian...), just swap around the bytes
//to convert the shorts to network endian.
for(i = 0; i < len; i+=2) {
    //swap(&pcZap[offset + i],&pcZap[offset + i + 1]);
    char tmp = pcZap[offset + i];
    pcZap[offset + i] =  pcZap[offset + i + 1]; 
    pcZap[offset + i + 1] = tmp;
}
//if you're on a big endian host, forget the above loop, the data
//is already in big/network endian layout.

//and just send the data.
if(sendto(sockFd,pcZap + offset,len,0,(struct sockaddr *)&Server_addr,
               sizeof Server_addr) == -1) {
   perror("sendto");
}
```

Note that your code had `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` in the sendto() call, which is wrong, you want it to be the actual size of Server_addr.